# Edges look sharp

Tags: edges

The edges are sharp making the sphere not smooth. I have applied the sub-surf modifier, but it does not appear to help smoothing the sphere. [image]
[image]

I have attached my final render model.

Comment: What is your problem? I see that the edges could use a bit of bevel, but what else?

Comment: Can you add you blend file? (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: You might want to include some screenshots showing your settings. This will help you get a faster response/solution.

Comment: Have you smoothed the mesh? (open up the Tool Shelf with **T**, then *Tools-Edit panel-Shading:Smooth*). How many *Subsurf Modifier* subdivisions you have?

Comment: blend file attach

Answer (score 2):

Turn up the Subsurf Modifiers

[image]

If the render is too sharp, turn the render subdivisions up to 3 or 4.
If the preview is too sharp, turn up the view subdivisions. Typicaly it is best practice to have lower preview subdivisions than render subdivisions.

Make sure that the object you want to modify is selected when you use the sub surf modifier.

For those of you who need more help, please watch the following gif that consists of 3 mouse clicks:

[image]

Also, make sure you do this with every single part of your model, otherwise some parts might have more creased edges.

Comment: i have attach my blend file plz go through its not working

Comment: @atek Make sure that the object you want to modify is selected when you use the sub surf modifier.

Comment: Plz tell me if the sub surf modifier or other modifier works from my side it did not work for me

Comment: @atek I can't actually test it right now because I'm in the middle of an intense render, but in a few hours I should be able to do it.

Comment: ok take ur time and plz tell me what it can work and which modifier is help for me to make the model smoother

Comment: @atek Use the subsurface modifier to make the model smoother. Make sure it is catmull-clark mode, otherwise it won't smooth.

Comment: @atek Try actually following my answer. None of your objects actually had the sub surf modifier on them

Answer (score 2):

While the answer given by 10 Replies is correct - you did not have sub-surf modifiers added to the objects - I think there is another problem. The edges of the front red spherical shape, and the back rear dark shape have slight deviations. The particular angle you have chosen for your composition shows very slightly the edge of the back object.

[image]

If you have a look at the edge in Edit Mode - you will see it is not what can be considered a clean topographical mesh. Presumably by either Boolean or the knife tool you have an edge that has triangles and this is where the sub-surf will try, but not necessarily solve the problem.

[image]

You could probably get away with just adjusting the angle a bit. If you do want to fix the edge, ideally you would want an edge loop where you might add a slight bevel to soften...